# Bad Request or no response when login if there are multiple Azure b2c login pages

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using Azure B2C for couple of our web applications. User could be using M365 Authentication or local account to login into our web applications via Azure B2C. Generally the authentication with Azure B2C works well although from time to time, we are running into the issue that end user could not login. With M365 account, end user would get a white page with bad request message there. For local account, end user just enters credential and clicks login and nothing happens. Here is the bad request screen shot:
[image]

From investigation, we found out that they have 2 browser tabs with same azure b2c login session since they clicked on our applications at different time and leave those tabs there. It doesn't happen very often, however once it happens, unfortunately this is a very bad experience for end users and there are no proper error messages or instructions for what end users should do next and they stuck without being able to move forward.  Anything we could do here to improve this experience? Or better, could Azure B2C add some enhancement to make this experience better since M365 login itself seems handling this scenario much better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We saw the same issue and Azure Support answered that the B2C simply doesn't allow multiple sign-ins within the same browser session. They said that this is a known issue and in queue for evaluation and there will eventually be a solution. There's a [public comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/11198/multiple-tab-login-ad-b2c-get-badrequest) about that too. That was back in November 2022 and I just (January 2024) tested this and it still hasn't been fixed.